# Should a migrated question's timestamp be reset?

Tags: support, migration, timestamps

When a question gets migrated it retains the timestamp from the original question, so that it essentially gets shuffled into the middle of the stack of questions on the new site.  This behavior is strange, as it seems like the question is being snuck (sneaked?) in the backdoor in the middle of night. This causes the question to go unnoticed both by users that could answer the question, and moderators/editors that could edit the question to fit better into the new site.

When a question is migrated, shouldn't it get a new timestamp? Essentially the question is being asked at that moment on the new site, and so should be placed in the queue appropriately.

Comment: I agree to some extent, but what about all of the other info that comes along with the question? Do we update the timestamps of any edits, comments, and answers that happened before migration too? Also note there is a (minor!) impact of shifting where the question sits in the askers own timeline. I think the original timestamp of the question is more important in the long run than where the question sits (temporarily!) on the front page.

Comment: @AaronBertrand No, all other timestamps remain intact.  Infact, maybe the migration becomes an "edit", which gets it's own timestamp. This might achieve the goal of having the question bumped to the front page.